# Modifying a python script to subtract three hours

Tags: python, date

I need to have this statement run on a time 3 hours earlier than the current time.

```py
import datetime

cmdline += datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime(" -m _ModelName_%Y%m%d_%H00")
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to apply that here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just directly applies the top-voted answer in the link that I posted in the comment above...

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

cmdline = ""

d = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=3)

cmdline += d.strftime(" -m _ModelName_%Y%m%d_%H00")

print(cmdline)
```